# iPhone screen capture for a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

On iphone, is it possible to "screen capture" an UIView and all its subview? If it is possible, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130424133005/http://reusablesnippets.posterous.com/capture-uiview), but I haven't tried it myself.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100731072942/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext:) you find the used  `-renderInContext`.

I transformed the code above to a category on UIView.
call  it like this: `[aView saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum];`

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (UIImage*)captureView {

    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);     
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];  
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
    return img;
}



- (void)saveScreenshotToPhotosAlbum {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self captureView], nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Comment: This will work for normal layers. OpenGl layers will not not show up in the screenshot. UIWebview screenshot will fail if the html will have -transform css.