# How to print a table view (any view) to an A4 PDF Document?

Tags: iphone, uiview, pdf-generation

I've a table view filled with data and I want to render the same view to an A4 PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is useful for you: [iPhone screen capture for a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487766/iphone-screen-capture-for-a-view/)

Here you find a gist I created to render an image of a view: https://gist.github.com/67f11f4968f3eb0aa095

**edit**

This will help you with the size

```
//CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];  
rect = [aTableView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my problem. The table view is printed upside down, beside it is not complete, if it has rows more than the view on the screen they will not appear.