# Not your typical Mapping App

Tags: xcode, dictionary, ios6, mapkit

I'm in the concept development stage of an iOS app that is essentially a game. One of the things I want to do is to get information about the current location. I've not used the map kit so far, and after a quick read through various documentation, it looks like it is designed mainly as a display kit. What I'd like to do in addition to displaying a map is to query data that might be at the location. For example, if I provide latitude and longitude, I want to know whether that location represents land or water. If it's on land, how close is it to the nearest street? If it's not near a street, what other information might there be about the spot?

I realize there are vast amounts of data available that are geocoded, but is there any information that can be queried directly from the map kit? I would have thought things like elevation would be easily available, but I haven't seen anything like that yet. Am I just looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no data that you can query directly from MapKit - i.e. you cannot ask MapKit if a location is on land or water.

You could use reverse geo-coding with the current longitude/latitude to find out details about the location, for example nearest street/town, or which country the location is in.

Check out the built in [Apple Geocoding framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html), or the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps tapping into something like openstreetmap is what I need.

Comment: Or maybe I could use screen captures of displayed maps [using code like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487766/iphone-screen-capture-for-a-view).